# Twilio Whitepages Pro Phone Reputation addon use with PHP

Tags: php, twilio

This is my first touch with Twilio Add-ons.
I want to use the addon "Whitepages Pro Phone Reputation" to return the relative results of a +ZZZZZZZ phone number. I have install the addon on the account (for the client id) and checked the use on Lookups on the control panel.
My PHP code is the following:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/Twilio/autoload.php');
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$client = new Client('XXXXXXX', 'YYYYYY');
$number = $client->lookups
    ->phoneNumbers("+ZZZZZZZ")
    ->fetch(
        array("type" => "carrier", "AddOns" => "whitepages_pro_phone_rep")
    );

var_dump($number->addOns['results']['whitepages_pro_phone_rep']);
```

But it returns the following:

```
array(5) { ["request_sid"]=> string(34) "XRcfbbe6fc969c3d20f5f0a95913a22cde" ["status"]=> string(6) "failed" ["message"]=> string(47) "Requirements to invoke AddOns have not been met" ["code"]=> int(61003) ["result"]=> array(0) { } }
```

What's the wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried going through their documentation? https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/block-spam-calls-and-robocalls-php-laravel#how-to-check-whitepages-pro-phone-reputation

Comment: Thanks for the link! I hadn't detected that, but I still don't understand how to achieve what I need. I need just a simple example to get the addon's results for a specific phone number. I'm don't understand fully the php example on the documentation page you quoted, but also I don't see, for example, the use of an argument for a phone number on the function/class.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are receiving an error there, the code is 61003. You can always search for error codes for Twilio and there is normally an explanatory page. Here is the explanation for [Error 61003](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/61003).

Sadly, that explanation doesn't have many solutions!

To me, it looks as though your code is correct, but I wonder whether you have installed and enabled the Add-on in your account for lookups. [Go here to install the Add-on](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons/XB56520d8bffd66533ca92b398596b8438), then make sure you have lookups selected.

[image: Select the check box next to Lookups]

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply philnash! Yes I have already "Lookups" selected on my dashboard. I was trying also to select all checkboxes, but the problem still exists. I turn it back to only "Lookups". Any other idea?

Comment: Ok, are you still using a free account or have you upgraded?

Comment: As I know it is a paid account (the account belongs to my client). I have access as developer to that and the addon is installed. Currently the account was used for phone verification (sms/call) etc. Let me know if you need any other info. :)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure then. Do you mind sending the account SID to me at philnash@twilio.com and I'll take a poke around.

Comment: I sent it to your e-mail. :) Once we have a solution, I will post it here for others too!

Answer (score 1):

I work for Whitepages and have some experience working within the Twilio environment. I've been the lead engineer for a couple of joint Twilio / Whitepages webinars and put together the app we used this year at Signal.

Have you tried testing it through a browser? Might be easy to see if it's the code or account / sub account. The mixing up the sid / token between a main account and a sub account has happened to me once.

https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+XXXXXXXXXXX/?AddOns=whitepages_pro_phone_rep

This will ask you for your account sid and auth token. Make sure you're getting a response there. Then at least we've narrowed it down.

Also when using the + Twilio expects E.169 formatted number numbers so make sure the country code is there.

Side note: It does look like you have "type" which should be "Type" for your carrier response but I don't think that will have an effect on AddOns.

Disclaimer: I've never worked in PHP.

We'll get it sorted out for you. Thanks for your support!

EDIT: Just noticed...would '$number->addOns' need to be '$number->add_ons'?

Answer (score 1):

I detected the problem. ohhh I was so stupid!
I did my tests using my own phone number (Vodafone Greece) but the service did not supports Greek phone numbers.

I do a test with a number from U.S.A. and it works as expected!